# how to load the selected check mat-selection-list

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

selection-list with check inside a reactive angular form, how can i show the checks that have already been selected?

html :

```
<mat-list-item>

                  <mat-selection-list formControlName="documents" disabled multiple >
                    <mat-list-option checkboxPosition="before" *ngFor="let document of setDocuments"
                                     [value]="document.codigo">
                      {{document.descripcion}}
                    </mat-list-option>
                  </mat-selection-list>
                </mat-list-item>
```

To see the details of the operation, load the following form control:

```
details(){

   let obj = this.data.objeto;
    let documents = obj.codigoSet;
    const usingSplit = documents.split(';');
    documents: new FormControl(usingSplit)
}
```

I do a split because the service returns the document codes as string, there I convert it to array but they are not shown selected

```
  <mat-list-item>

                  <mat-selection-list formControlName="documents" disabled multiple >
                    <mat-list-option checkboxPosition="before" *ngFor="let document of setDocuments"
                                     [value]="document.codigo" [selected]="selectList">
                      {{document.descripcion}}
                    </mat-list-option>
                  </mat-selection-list>
                </mat-list-item>
```

try adding the property [selected] and create a variable boolean "selectList" and call the service of all the documents and compare with the code I have but when trying to assign that answer to the variable selectList it gives me error

```
  selectList:boolean;


export class Document  {


details(){

   let obj = this.data.objeto;
    let documents = obj.codigoSet;
    const usingSplit = documents.split(';');

  this.setForView.subscribe( data =>{
         data.map((item) => ({
        ...item,

        this.selectList: usingSplit.some((el) => // error
          el === item.codigo
        )
      }));
      }
    );
    documents: new FormControl(usingSplit)
}


}
```

I think comparing the list I have with the response of the service is the solution but I can't find the way.

Answer (score 0):

mat-selection list multiple store an array, so the only you need is give value to the formControl. But this value need to be an array (please don't confussed with a FormArray)

If your data becomes like, e.g.

```
data={documents:"1;2;5"} //documenst is a string
```

You simply

```
documents:new FormControl(data.documents.split(";"))
```